# Add Nested XML Node to xml File using Asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I Want add some url to xml file on my website using C#.

I have already create a XML file on website Root.
The content of xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9&#xD;&#xA;http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.structure.com/Structure.aspx?id=1</loc>
      </url>
</urlset>
```

Now I want add new `<url>` Node with `<loc>` node to xml file and I want xml content changes like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9&#xD;&#xA;http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.structure.com/Structure.aspx?id=1</loc>
      </url>
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.structure.com/Structure.aspx?id=2</loc>
      </url>
</urlset>
```

I try made a function that get url string from web form and it's triggers on asp:Button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        insertSiteMap("http://www.structure.com/Structure.aspx?id=2");
    }
```

And the function is:

```
private void insertSiteMap(string pageurl)
    {
        //Load XML Schema
        System.Xml.XmlDocument originalXml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        originalXml.Load(Server.MapPath("../sitemap.xml"));
        XmlElement URL = originalXml.CreateElement("url");

        XmlElement LOC = originalXml.CreateElement("loc");
        XmlText LOCText = originalXml.CreateTextNode(pageurl);
        LOC.AppendChild(LOCText);

        URL.AppendChild(LOC);

        XmlNode newUrl = originalXml.GetElementsByTagName("url")[0];
        originalXml.DocumentElement.PrependChild(newUrl);

        originalXml.Save(Server.MapPath("../sitemap.xml"));
    }
```

I don't have any error and visual studio message me xml file has been modified but when I open the file there is no any changes on xml file :(.

 am I did wrong any where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have created the new element with your variable `URL`, you need to insert with e.g.  `originalXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(URL);`.

However, take note that in your original XML you use a namespace while your C# code creates the new XmlElements in no namespace, so you need to fix the element creation as well, e.g.

```
XmlElement url = originalXml.CreateElement("url", originalXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlElement loc = originalXml.CreateElement("loc", originalXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
loc.InnerText = pageurl;
url.AppendChild(loc);
originalXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(url);
```